# Efficient way to synchronize threads executing code in different classes?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety

I've just wondering whether it would possible to manage a Windows Forms progress bar in a such an "experimental" way:

- I would like to control the bar from the main form during I have a thread executing code in a *WorkerClass* object which contains a function *doWork* to do the heavy calculations.
- The *WorkerClass* contains two member variables that are updated by the *doWork* function and that are accessed from the form to synchronize threads and to keep traking of the work already completed.
- As I need to provide thread safety to these member variables, I build two *synclocking* objects in the main form and pass them to *doWork* function
- The *doWork* function returns a value that the main form needs in order to complete his job, so I found tricky the fact I have to tell the form thread to wait until the return value.

  This is the *WorkerClass* code:

  ```
  Public Class WorkerClass
          Private mBarValue As Integer
          Private mStartNow As Boolean

          Public ReadOnly Property BarValue
                  Get
                          Return mBarValue
                  End Get
          End Property

          Public ReadOnly Property StartNow As Boolean
                  Get
                          Return mStartNow
                  End Get
          End Property

          Public Sub New()
                  mBarValue = 0
                  mStartNow = False
          End Sub

          Public Function doWork(ByRef list As ArrayList) As Integer

                  SyncLock (list.Item(0))
                          mStartNow = True
                  End SyncLock

                  'Do your work and update status
                  For i As Integer = 0 To 99
                          Thread.Sleep(10)
                          SyncLock (list.Item(1))
                                  mBarValue += 1
                          End SyncLock
                  Next

                  SyncLock (list.Item(0))
                          mStartNow = False
                  End SyncLock

                  Return 1000

          End Function

  End Class
  ```

And this is the main form code:

```
    Public Class Form1
        Private lock As Object
        Private lock2 As Object
        Private integerNeeded As Integer

        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Me.lock = New Object()
            Me.lock2 = New Object()
            Dim wc As New WorkerClass()
            Dim wT As New Thread(AddressOf workerThread)

            Me.ProgressBar1.Value = 0
            Me.ProgressBar1.Show()

            wT.Start(wc)

            Dim canStart As Boolean = False

            While Not canStart
                SyncLock (lock)
                    canStart = wc.StartNow
                End SyncLock
            End While
            Debug.WriteLine("Start")

            'Bar updater
            Dim currentProgress As Integer = 0

            While canStart
                SyncLock (lock2)
                    currentProgress = wc.BarValue
                End SyncLock

                If currentProgress Mod Me.ProgressBar1.Step = 0 Then
                    Me.ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
                    Debug.WriteLine(Me.ProgressBar1.Value)
                End If

                SyncLock (lock)
                    canStart = wc.StartNow
                End SyncLock
            End While

            While wT.IsAlive 'Wait until the thread is done. Need to guarantee the value is returned
            End While

            Debug.WriteLine("End")
            Me.ProgressBar1.Hide()

            REM Rest of the code with integerNeeded here...

        End Sub

        Private Sub workerThread(wc As Object)
            Dim locks As New ArrayList()
            locks.Add(lock)
            locks.Add(lock2)
            integerNeeded = wc.doWork(locks)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

**My question:** This seems to work, but I find it slow and even I do not trust very much in it, is there a more efficient way to implement it ? I have searched for examples but I did not find anything with a thread executing code in a different class like so.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the built  in methods provided by .net for synchronization likes of AutoResetEvent and ManualResetEvent. For Example

ManualResetEvent maintains a boolean variable in memory. When the boolean variable is false then it blocks all threads and when the boolean variable is true it unblocks all threads.
 Start your different tasks in separate thread with the help of Task Parallel Library for example

```
        Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            GetFoo();
        });

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            ShowFoo();
        });

 //Have an instance of manual reset event 
        static ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new 
        ManualResetEvent(false);


  //Send first signal to get Foo then reset it to wait 
        manualResetEvent.Set();
        manualResetEvent.Reset();


  //It will wait until  manualResetEvent is Set again
        manualResetEvent.Set();

   Here is a great article that can help you understand the concepts of synchronization. 
    http://dotnetpattern.com/threading-manualresetevent
```